# Can $\lambda_i$'s root subspace be divided into several eigenspaces direct sum?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace

Let $W_{\lambda_i}$ be $\lambda_i$'s root subspace of linear transformation $\mathscr{A}$.

I just learned $W_{\lambda_i}$ can be represented as direct sum of some cyclic subspaces such as $W_{\lambda_i}=C_{j1}\oplus C_{j2}\oplus \cdots C_{js}$. I want to know if root space $W_{\lambda_i}$ can be represented as direct sum of some eigensubspaces? What's the relationship between cyclic subspace and eigensubspace? And I'm confused of these subspaces' geometric explanation, help.

Comment: I'm guessing by "root subspace" you mean the generalized eigenspace? The set of all $v$ such that $(\mathscr{A}-\lambda I)^kv = \mathbf{0}$ for some $k\geq 0$?

Comment: Yes they are same thing

Comment: The generalized eigenspace is a sub of eigenspaces if and only if it is equal to the eigenspace itself (that is, all its nonzero elements are eigenvectors). Otherwise, you cannot so express it. Each of the cyclic subgroups "ends" (or begins, depending on how you define them) in an eigenvector, and those terminal vectors form a basis of the eigenspace. This is all discussed in detail in the Jordan Canonical Form.